# Nomenclature package error : Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment

Tags: nomenclature

I am using the package `nomencl` to generate a list of abbreviations. However, after a recent MiKTeX 2.9 update (using TeXnicCenter) I keep getting errors for the abbreviation items

```
LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
```

Unfortunately, I cannot figure out an MWE (the MWE that I tried do work, but the real document doesn't). So here is a shortened version of my main document (without all the other header stuff and bibliography):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl} 
\let\abk\nomenclature   
\renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Abbreviations}
\let\OrgItem\item
\renewcommand\nompreamble{\renewcommand\item[1][]{\OrgItem[##1]\dotfill    
\hspace{\labelsep}}}    
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}   
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
\printnomenclature \newpage
\include{Introduction}
\include{Methods}
\include{Results}
\end{document}
```

However, if instead of including the chapters I simply try out an MWE with the same header and one abbreviation:

```
\begin{document}
\printnomenclature \newpage
This is my txt \abk{txt}{text}
\end{document}
```

then everything works fine. Any suggestions about the reason?

Comment: Try to successively remove parts of the main document until the error disappears.

Comment: Try `\input` instead of `\include`.

Comment: @gerrit: Due to the kind of the error message I thought it is a general problem rather than text-dependent. I followed your advice and after 2 hours trying to narrow down the problem area I finally found the reason: One of the abbreviations was defined twice.

Comment: @Anja: Please turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: @lockstep: I think this isn't an answer. I think we should close this question as to localized. If she edit her question it will be enough.

Comment: This is why making a  minimal example should be done _before_ asking a question…

Comment: @Seamus: Indeed!

Comment: @Seamus: That's what I was trying to do for a while, wondering why the supposed MWE works. Due to the kind of error message (missing environment) and to the fact that the errors occurred for all items I thought it's a more general problem, e.g. with the "include" commands or something similar.

Comment: @Anja If you thought it was a problem with `\include` then a minimal example involving `\include` should have been your first test. I've learned a lot more from building MWEs than I have from the answers I get when I find one that works (or doesn't)

Comment: @Seamus: Fair enough! I absolutely agree that building MWEs is helpful. I am not very experienced with LaTeX, but I usually manage to resolve most of the occurring problems either this way or by narrowing down the problem area. In this particular case, I was really puzzled so that I didn't see another way rather than asking the community. I am grateful for gerrit's hint and indeed I learned a lesson about problem solving strategies from this topic. Now, I don't think that further off-topic discussion will be helpful for anyone.

Answer (score 17):

The problem was, that one of the abbreviations was defined twice. After removing the duplicate item everything works fine.

Comment: You saved my day, a similar problem was bugging me, and your note on duplicate definitions solved my problem. Which was indeed caused by duplicate nomenclature definitions.